# swiper.js | start autoplay swiper only when user scroll to slider id

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

how to start swiper Autoplay when user scroll to swiper wrapper id
It usually runs automatically when opening the page

how can i control autoplay events ?

This is example:
https://codepen.io/elostoracom/pen/ExgRNvP

And here is the js code

```js
new Vue({
  el: ".home-slider",
  data() {
    return {
      homeSwiper: "",
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.homeSwiper = new Swiper(".home-slider", {
      updateOnWindowResize: true,
      loop: true,
      slidesPerView: 1.5,
      spaceBetween: 10,
      speed: 500,
      centeredSlides: true,
      centeredSlidesBounds: true,
      autoplay: {
        delay: 1000,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
      },
      pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        clickable: true,
      },
    });
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

> how can i control autoplay events ?

You can use `swiper.autoplay.start()` to start the autoplay and `swiper.autoplay.stop()` to stop the auto play imperatively.

> how to start swiper Autoplay when user scroll to swiper wrapper id It usually runs automatically when opening the page

Intersection Observer lets you know when an element is in view. It's got a good support in the (modern) browsers, but if you want it to work in all browsers, you can use the polyfill.

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/c0m1t/pen/wvzXoNN)

Comment: thx ,Can it be done without using vue As in your example ?

Comment: @AhmedElzelaky Yes you can use it as Vanilla JavaScript, in React, jQuery, Vue ...